# F# from list of list to set of set

Tags: f#

So I have a function which computes the powerset of a set:

```
let rec powerset = function
  | [] -> [[]]
  | x::xs -> List.collect (fun subset -> [subset; x::subset]) (powerset xs)
```

This returns `'a list list`.

Now I'm trying to make a function which gives me all the subsets with a certain length `k`.

```
let rec allSubsets n k =
    let powersetN = Set.ofList (powerset [1..n])
    let subsets ps = 
        Set.filter (fun e -> Set.count e = k) ps
    subsets powersetN
```

The thing is, `powersetN` is a `Set<int list>`, whereas `subsets` expect a `Set<Set<'a>>`.

The obvious solution of course would be to create the powerset as an actual set instead of a list, but I haven't been able to come up with a way to do this.

Any hints?

Comment: `powerset [1..n]
        |> List.map Set.ofList
        |> Set.ofList`

Comment: ^ Does it what you want?

Comment: That seems to do the trick.

Comment: or you can rewrite your method `powerset`

Comment: That's also what I thought would be the best solution, but I'm a little stuck on how.

Comment: if you don't want implement the algorithm in term of Set you can map result the same as in the code above

Comment: `| x::xs -> List.collect (fun subset -> [subset; x::subset]) (powerset xs) |> List.map Set.ofList |> Set.ofList` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158779/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and-khaine775).